# UIWebView sharp corners

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, quartz-core

I have an UIWebView with and using QuartzCore to add some style to this. But when i'm execute:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width-20.0, self.view.bounds.size.height-30.0)];

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
webView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
webView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I get an rounder View but content is sharp. There is a way to roundend corners in content in WebView
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content view is actually the `scrollView` of `UIWebView`, so

```
webView.scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @graver Answer but not completely Coz His working will not work on iphone 3g and iPod 2nd generation .

```
webView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[webView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

ClipsToBound will simple resize all the subviews under webView.